# How do I remove specific elements from HTML with HTML Agility Pack for ASP.NET (vb)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html-agility-pack

There seems to be no documentation on the codeplex page and for some reason intellisense doesn't show me available methods or anything at all for htmlagilitypack (for example when I type MyHtmlDocument.DocumentNode. - there is no intellisense to tell me what I can do next)

I need to know how to remove ALL < a > tags and their content from the body of the HTML document I cannot just use Node.InnerText on the Body because that still returns content from A tags.

Here is example HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        I was born in <a name=BC>Toronto</a> and now I live in barrie
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to return

```
I was born in and now I live in barrie
```

Thanks, I appreciate the help!

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets you the result you require. This uses Recursive method to drill down all your html nodes and you can simply remove more nodes by adding a new if statment.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim document = New HtmlDocument() With { _
        Key .OptionOutputAsXml = True _
    }
    document.LoadHtml("<html><body>I was born in <a name=BC>Toronto</a> and now I live in barrie</body></html>")

    For i As var = 0 To document.DocumentNode.ChildNodes.Count - 1
        RecursiveMethod(document.DocumentNode.ChildNodes(i))
    Next

    Console.Out.WriteLine(document.DocumentNode.InnerHtml.Replace("  ", " "))
End Sub

Public Sub RecursiveMethod(child As HtmlNode)
    For x As var = 0 To child.ChildNodes.Count - 1
        Dim node = child.ChildNodes(x)
        If node.Name = "a" Then
            node.RemoveAll() //removes all the child nodes of "a"
            node.Remove()    //removes the actual "a" node
        Else
            If node.HasChildNodes Then
                RecursiveMethod(node)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this method. As of now, I'm just outputting all the html and setting display: none; CSS on the a tags until my boss determines whether we need this 'untagged' content or not.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of (sorry my code is C# but I hope it will help nonetheless)

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

doc.LoadHtml("some html markup here");

HtmlNodeCollection links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@name]");

foreach(HtmlNode link in links)
{
    link.Remove();
}

//then one of the many doc.Save(...) overrides to actually get the result of the operation.
```